# Where can I find legitimate wood shed designs?

Tags: shed

Where is a good place to find good shed designs?

Googling around just gives me a bunch of poorly designed websites that scam people into their site by advertising free designs and charging for them. If they need to advertise like that, I can't assume their plans are that great.

I'm looking to build an 8x10 wood shed on a concrete slab.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at your local Lowe's, Home Depot or even Amazon online book store.  They have several books with lots of different designs.  You can look them over and just buy the book that suits your needs.  They will have diagrams and material lists.  Also these books are fairly cheap.  Good luck.

Comment: Not to mention that Lowe's and HD many times have pre-built units out front that you can look over as to how they are assembled.   I have found a few of the book plans match the forsale units exactly.

Answer (score 8):

This [website](http://www.todaysplans.net/find-free-shed-plans.html) has quite a few links for free plans. They're a mix of slab plans and elevated floor plans. You'll have to click through several levels down, but here are some direct links to some of the nicer ones:

[Basic 6'x8' shed plan with cinder block base. (Expandable up to 8'x12').](http://www.todaysplans.net/PopularMechanics-Super-Shed.pdf)

[Larger 8'x12' shed plan with double doors.](http://www.todaysplans.net/BlackDecker-12x8-Shed.pdf)

This [site](https://legacy.rd.com/offer/fh/project_plans/plans.jsp?xedni=24&id=3) is also listed under the first link (with enough clicking in the right spots), and it's got 6 PDF plans available directly on it's page.

Comment: great find, thanks! i especially like the larger plan

Answer (score 0):

I have used iCreatables shed design. I had to send in a few corrections and it was lacking in some detail but otherwise it was fine. It meets code and was designed inexpensively. They also provide a lot of documentation for how to build a shed to go along with their design.